# For system_auth default Class should be SimpleStrategy or NetworkTopologyStrategy

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

In our Prod cluster, I see some of the **system*** keyspaces with SimpleStrategy.
As we are adding new DCs in our cluster we need to be on NetworkTopologyStrategy otherwise while I am running nodetool rebuild, It got failed.

I alter all keyspaces from SimpleStrategy to NetworkTopologyStrategy & rebuild works well.

During ALTER it gives warning also that you are altering system keyspace.

Another question: **Opscenter Keyspace(rollup* tables)** is having a hell lot of data, why I should replicate that, it should be enough to put on only 1 DC??

My question what should be the ideal strategy for system* keyspaces??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question what should be the ideal strategy for system* keyspaces?

A little warning on this one.  `system` and `system_schema` have a special replication strategy of `LocalStrategy`, and they should stay that way.

The other keyspaces of `system_auth`, `system_distributed`, and `system_traces` however, are a different story.  Setting those to use `NetworkTopologyStrategy` with a RF 3 (assuming each DC has at least 3 nodes) for each DC is perfectly acceptable.  Setting that for `system_distributed`, and `system_traces` isn't *as* important, but it shouldn't hurt anything.

On the other hand, `system_auth` **should definitely be set to use `NetworkTopologyStrategy` with a RF specified for each DC**.  The reason, is that `SimpleStrategy` could potentially put all of its replicas in a single DC, or even zero replicas in one DC.  That could cause high latency or even timeouts for auth checks, as that would result in cross-DC network traffic.

Also, if your applications use DC-specific load balancing policies, you *will* need to specify a RF for each DC in `system_auth`.  As mentioned above, using `SimpleStrategy` could result in a DC not getting any replicas for a user.  And than *would* prevent DC-specific applications from connecting.